# Xcode: Your target contains an unsupported Swift Version

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting this popup when I open my project in XCode 12, but I can compile the app fine:

[image: Unsupported Swift Version]

It says

> The target  contains source code developed with Swift
> 3.x. This version of Xcode does not support building or migrating Swift 3.x targets.
>
> Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4.

I am using Cordova so perhaps there's some legacy Swift code somewhere.
My question is how do I find out what swift files Xcode means? Any way to search for them?

I tried the logging from XCode in Console.app but found nothing there.

Comment: It's not about Swift files or Swift code. It's about the target (you've covered up the name). You need to do what the dialog says. Fix this with Xcode 10.1. Xcode 12 won't even show you a Swift 3 build setting.

Comment: However, the target has a swift version of 4 configured in build settings. I'd try Xcode 10.1 if it launched, but it won't. (not sure if because of Big Sur?) Anyway if I grep my project I just see entries like this:  SWIFT_VERSION = 4.0; So I wish to know where Xcode gets the idea ..

Comment: You have to pass thru actual migration.

Comment: I tried this: find . | grep -i "\.swift$" | while read l; do swiftc -parse -swift-version 5 "$l"; done and it finished without errors.. hm. so i don't see what to migrate ..